# Difference between Woodling::saved and Woodling::retrieve

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, phpunit, eloquent

I am writing my unit tests with `phpunit` to `Laravel` application. I am using `Eloquent` and [`Woodling` library](https://github.com/summerstreet/woodling). I want to test many to many relationship.

I have `Users` table and `Friends` table. Everything worked, when I tested it manually. I am able to add friends. I wanted to test this functionality.

I created blueprints and I call them with `saved` method like this.

```
$user = Woodling::saved('LonelyUser');
$user2 = Woodling::saved('LonelyUser2');
$users = User::all()->toArray();
var_dump($users);
$user->addFriend($user2);
```

I got a database constraint error in the last line, because the users were not persisted to database (I know that, because they are not in `var_dump` output).

If `Woodling::saved` does not persist to database, than what does it do? The docs say, that it calls `save` method on model. `save` method should persist the model to database.

What is the `saved` method purpose and how is it different than `retrieve`?

Answer (score 0):

`Woodling::saved` persists to database correctly, but if something goes wrong during saving, it doesn't show any errors. In my case `save` method was actually `Ardent::save`, which does some validations. This validations did not pass and `Model::save` was never called.